# How do I check if an json includes an value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, contains

i want to check if a date value is a holiday. For this I am using a rest api:

https://feiertage-api.de/api/?jahr=2018&nur_land=HE

I have this function for that and try something like that:

```
VacationRequest.checkHoliday = function(selectedDay,restApi){

    console.log("CURRENT DAY : ",selectedDay.getFullYear() + "-" + selectedDay.getMonth() + "-" + selectedDay.getDate());

    console.log("RESTAPI - DATE : ",restApi[0].datum); // not define

    return false;
}
```

How do I check if a JSON includes a value in JavaScript? In this context, how do I check if a particular value corresponding to a key `datum` is a holiday?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: How do I check if an json includes an value in JavaScript?

Comment: @Tarasov do you mean that  you want to check if the object restApi[0] has  the following property  "datum" or not  after parsing the json?  then you could use   [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

i think,first you can parse json to be an object

Answer (score 0):

Get your bytes from the server, e.g. via jQuery AJAX or Node's `https.get()`, then pass them to JSON.parse() to convert that to a JavaScript `Object`:

```
result = JSON.parse(bytes);
console.log(result);
```